# How to display log events from multiple log groups by string

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I would like to be able to see log events from multiple log groups and log streams in CloudWatch in one place (on one screen).

When a request comes to api gateway it will create a token that will be used when requesting other downstream services. So lets say 10 different services will produce log events that contain token that api-gateway created. Each service will crate these log events in its own log group and even log stream (one log stream per container). How can I filter by string and see all log events containing same token in one place?